# how to type "->" efficient in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm learning **Kotlin**.

I don't want to type "-" + ">" to get "->",so how can I type this symbol quickly?

Note- IDE is Android Studio.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html#custom this might help ...

Comment: What would you rather type? Have you looked at [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/live-templates.html)?

Answer (score 3):

uses `ALT+ENTER` and then choose makes the parameters explicitly / specify the lambda signature.

```
//  move the cursor here `ALT+ENTER` specify the lambda signature
//                        v
val sum: (Int) -> Unit = {
    it
//  ^--- move the cursor here `ALT+ENTER` to makes the parameters explicitly
};
```

**OR** uses `CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE`.

```
val sum: (Int) -> Unit = { }
//                        ^--- move the cursor here `CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE`
```